# Identify single item in a list

Tags: list

What attributes uniquely identify an item in a SharePoint 2010 list? For example, I want to programmatically find all items in a list, given only the URL of the list's location. Then I want to iterate over all of the list's items, creating a "UniqueListItem" object for each item in the list. What properties would that UniqueListItem need, to be able to uniquely identify an item in the list? I think each SP list has a unique list GUID, and then each item within that list has an integer identifying it. Is that correct? And how would I programmatically find those things? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the list. If `GetListFromUrl` throws an exception the list doesn't exist. If it does, iterate over your SPListItem collection.

```
SPList list;
try {list = web.GetListFromUrl("http://sharepoint/sites/wea/Lists/TestList"); }
catch { list = null; } //list does not exist

if (list != null)
{
    SPListItemCollection itemCollection = list.Items;
    foreach (SPListItem item in itemCollection)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Though I believe your code has some typos since you assigned list the value null.

Comment: No. I declared the list, then entered the try catch. As I mentioned in my post, the line list = web.GetListFromUrl("http://sharepoint/sites/wea/Lists/TestList"); will throw an exception if the list doesn't exist. I'm catching that exception and assigning it a null value.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I see what you did there. Though 'list' will already be null if the GetListFromUrl method throws an exception.

Comment: Marked as correct yet Tim didn't actually answer the question about the primary key of the list item?

Comment: Short of the extra text in the OP, my provided solution does exactly what he asked for. Find a list, given the URL. Then, iterate over each of the list items.

Comment: A little late to the show, but just curious, does this actually work? I think `GetListFromUrl` is just an alias for `GetListFromWebPartPageUrl` (disassemble), and there you might need an actual page (with a view), such as __/AllItems.aspx__

Answer (score 2):

The list can be identified by URL and has a GUID ID.

Items within the list have a unique integer [ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.id.aspx), *and* a GUID [UniqueId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.uniqueid.aspx). The SPList class has both [GetItemById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitembyid.aspx) and [GetItemByUniqueId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitembyuniqueid.aspx) methods. Given the choice, the normal Int ID is normally used.

Comment: +1 for being very comprehensive - I didn't know that list items had a GUID as well as the ID.

Comment: +1 for being so thorough. I did notice that when I looked through the SPList class but when I posted this question I didn't know that SPList was used for SP2010. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0):

The SPList object has a GetItemById method